# Sort an array with integers and letters alphabetic in Angular / Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

## What I plan to do

I try to sort an array like this...

- 1
- 2
- 2(a)
- 2(b)
- 2(b) #AsimpleName
- 2(b) #NameWithN
- 3
- 4
- 4(a)
- ...

... in Angular2.

## My Current Code

**Component**

```
this.streetDetailRef = this.afDatabase.list('data/users/' + this.currentUserID + '/territory/' + this.sStreet.parentKey + '/' + this.sStreet.key + '/houseNumbers/');
this.streetDetailData = this.streetDetailRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() })).sort();
});
```

**The loop in my view**

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let house of streetDetailData | async | orderBy: 'number':false" #slidingItem>
<strong>{{ house.number }}</strong> ...
```

`'number'` in this case is the clean number without letter. I store the letter in a separate firebase entry. But sure would be possible to store them in the same if needed.

Additional information: I'm using the ngx-orderBy-pipe by VadimDez: https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe

## The current result

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function should do the trick:

```
function sortData(array: Array<number | string>): Array<number | string> {
    return array.sort((a, b) => a < b ? -1 : 1);
}
```

And here is use example:

```
const sorted = sortData(['4(a)', 4, 3, '2(b) #NameWithN', '2(b) #AsimpleName']); 
sorted // [ '2(b) #AsimpleName', '2(b) #NameWithN', 3, 4, '4(a)' ]
```

Comment: @Hav - This will be my new goto function for sorting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** While my answer works, the accepted answer is better and I will adopt it for use in the future.

You can use this simple compare function, along with Typescript's built-in `sort()` function to get the answers you want.

Typescript:

```
function sortStrings(a: string, b: string) {
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
}

console.log(['4(a)', '3', '2', '2(b) secondName', 
 '2(b)firstName','2(b)','2(a)', '4', '1'].sort(sortStrings));
```

Output:

```
[ '1',
  '2',
  '2(a)',
  '2(b)',
  '2(b) firstName',
  '2(b) secondName',
  '3',
  '4',
  '4(a)' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Typescript you can sort any collection which you have. Following is a code sample which might help you. I guess treating your id as string will solve the problem.

```
let names: [string];
    let numbers: [number];
    names.sort(this.sortByLetter);
    numbers.sort(this.sortByNumber);

sortByLetter(string1: string, string2: string) {
    if (string1 > string2) return 1
    else if (string1 === string2) return 0
    else return -1;
}


sortByNumber(n1: number, n2: number) {
    return n2 - n1;
}
```